# What is the origin of the bubble during sleep trope?

Tags: tropes

A common trope across various anime and manga is the [snot bubble trope](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SnotBubble). I've put an example below:

[image]

I can gather what it signifies from the [TV Tropes description](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SnotBubble), but what's the origin of this? Does anybody know where it was first used, or where the inspiration came from?

Comment: Could it come from little babies who have running noses all the time and when they fall asleep after a tiring day of running around it might create snot bubbles...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The origin is, perhaps surprisingly, real life! This does occur among [children in Japan](https://www.flickr.com/photos/altus/1515466596) and [in other countries as well](http://jemblankz-monstervikings.blogspot.jp/2011/06/funny-snot-bubble.html).

[image]

[image]

Comment: It looks significantly less appealing in real life D:

Comment: +1. It looks like I guess right in the end xp. Although I did not want to be right, this is disgusting lol.

Comment: Needs a disclaimer for disturbing content.